# In EC with key chaining, is it possible to verify signature made by root private key using public key of derived keypair?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature

I am not sure whether crypto.SE is the right place for this question, but I assume this is closest to on-topic here.

I am doing personal research on cryptography using elliptic curves. I can see that many projects starting to utilize deterministic key derivation (my terminology may be off here, see below what I mean by it).

What I am wondering is whether knowing how derivation process is done, is it possible to verify signature made my root private key using child public key?

Assuming:

```
random -> root keypair (rootPriv, rootPub) -> KDF(rootPriv) = childPriv, KDF(rootPub) = childPub
```

Then assuming two parties Alice and Bob:

- Alice holds rootPriv/rootPub and childPriv/childPub.
- Bob holds only childPub.
- Alice wants to send `message` to Bob and ensure Bob receives it untampered. Alice then signs `message` using `rootPriv` and sends to Bob `message` and `signature`.

How can Bob (if it all possible) verify the signature knowing `KDF` and `childPub` without knowing `rootPriv/rootPub/childPriv`?

If that is possible for EC, does such requirement pose any restrictions on which curve can be used or on `KDF`? E.g. can any curve be used (Ed25519 or any other?) and would KDF need to be reversible in nature or any other restriction?

PS: This is about EC strictly though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about what are called *hierarchical signature schemes* or *blinded signature schemes*.  There's a root private key $a$ and public key $A$, and for any tweak $t$, there is a derived private key $a_t = f(a, t)$, and a derived public key $A_t = F(A, t)$, such that signatures made with $a_t$ can be verified by $A_t$, but the set $\{A_t\}_t$ is supposed to be indistinguishable from $\{A'_t\}_t$ for any other $A'$ to anyone who doesn't know $A$.  See [an earlier answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50698/49826) for some references.

I think you're further asking about whether there is an easy way to compute $A$ given $A_t$ and $t$, although you didn't mention $t$ so maybe there is only one possible derived key pair.  Whether you can do this depends on the specific signature scheme, so let's pick one for illustration:

**Signatures.**
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\concat}{\mathop{\Vert}}$Let $k$ be the field $\Z/(2^{255} - 19)\Z$, and let $E/k$ be the twisted Edwards curve $$E/k\colon -x^2 + y^2 = 1 - (121665/121666) x^2 y^2,$$ whose group $E(k)$ of $k$-rational points has order $h\ell$ for large prime $\ell$ and cofactor $h = 8$.  A public key is a point $A \in E(k)$, and a signature on a message $m$ is an encoded pair $(R, s)$ of $R \in E(k)$ and a 253-bit integer $s$ satisfying the verification equation $$[h s] B = [h] R + [h H(R\concat A\concat m)]\,A,$$ where $B$ is the standard base point and $H$ is the standard hash function mapping long messages to 512-bit integers.

A signer chooses a secret 256-bit scalar $a$ (usually with $a \equiv 0 \pmod h$ and $2^{254} < a < 2^{255}$ so that it is compatible with X25519 secrets, but this is irrelevant to signature security) and a secret 256-bit string $\kappa$ as their private key, and publishes $A = [a]B$ as their public key.  To sign message $m$, they compute $r = H(\kappa\concat m)$, $R = [r]B$, and $$s \equiv r + H(R\concat A\concat m)\,a \pmod \ell.$$

**Hierarchical signatures.**
So far this is just standard Ed25519.  For a tweak $t$, we can let
\begin{align*}
  a_t &\equiv a H(A\concat t) \pmod \ell, \\
  A_t &= [H(A\concat t)] A.
\end{align*}
Note that $$A_t = [H(A\concat t)]([a]B) = [a H(A\concat t)]B = [a_t]B,$$ so that $A_t$ is the ordinary Ed25519 public key for the private key $a_t$.

**Question.**
In this hierarchical signature scheme, given $A_t$ and $t$ but not $A$, and given a signature $(R, s)$ on a message $m$ under key $A$, can we verify the signature?

Suppose $H(A\concat t)$ is coprime with $\ell$; then it has a multiplicative inverse, say $\xi$, modulo $\ell$, so that $$\xi H(A\concat t) \equiv 1 \pmod \ell.$$  If $A_t$ is a scalar multiple of the order-$\ell$ point $B$, then $$[\xi]A_t = [\xi]([H(A\concat t)]A) = [\xi H(A\concat t)]A = A.$$
Thus we can recover $A$ from $A_t$ and $t$, and use that to verify the signature $(R, s)$ on $m$.

Under uniform random choice of $H$, then probability that $\ell$ divides $H(A\concat t)$ is negligible; under the standard $H$ based on SHA-512, the overwhelming majority of outputs are not multiples of $\ell$.  If this bothers you on aesthetic grounds (the probability is so small it is inconsequential for security), you could use $H(A\concat t) \bmod 2^{252}$ instead of $H(A\concat t)$ in the above protocol.

Adapting this to other hierarchical signature schemes and other curves is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I will need to revisit some of my university math memories. However from your explanation it is that the At=F(A,t) must be reversible in nature, so that the process of verification begins with getting A based on known At,t. Would there be any ways to achieve the same with F(A,t) being irreversible? (I presume there may be not, but I may be wrong about that).

Comment: This system works because $F_t\colon A \mapsto F(A, t)$ is reversible, yes.  Is there another way to do this in some signature scheme without recovering $A$ as an intermediate step?  Maybe, maybe not.  Certainly the _easiest_ way to design a cryptosystems with the properties you sought is to make $F_t$ reversible.  In the case of Ed25519, you definitely need to recover $A$, because the verifier has to be able to compute computes $H(R\mathop\Vert A\mathop\Vert m)$.